# Rails ERB error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a CRUD blog application, and wrote this code:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for :article , url:articles_path do|f| %>
  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize%>
      </h2>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :title %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :text %><br/>
      <%= f.text_area :text %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit%>
    </p>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

My page shows `` undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass ``. What should I fix here?

The controller is:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  # new form method
  def new

  end

  # create method
  def create
    @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title,:text))       
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end     
  end

  #Show method
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  # New method
  def new

  end

  #index method
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end
end
```

And the full backtrace is here:

```
app/views/articles/new.html.erb:5:in `block in _app_views_articles_new_html_erb___837982527363082027_69849494310700'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:444:in `form_for'
app/views/articles/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_articles_new_html_erb___837982527363082027_69849494310700'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/prio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/home/prio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/prio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/prio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Requires full backrace of error.

Comment: You have to pass `@article` from your controller method, suppose this is `new.html.erb` page then in controller you will have `new` method in that `@article = Article.new`. Post your controller code

Comment: in `new` method just add `@article = Article.new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the method 'new'. This may work:

`def new
  @article = Article.new
end`

And you have two 'new' methods. Erase one.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `new` your variable `@article` is undefined. You don't need that code in your form. You should put that code in your show or what ever view you go to after creating the new article.

Edit: I see you are redirecting back to `new` if the save fails. At that point it would be defined. I would change the code to check if `@article` is defined first:

```
 <% if @article.errors %>
```

this will handle the situation of `@article` being undefined because it hasn't been called yet.